# Concatenate Variable in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

Below is my code.
Supposedly I wanted to concatenate the variable $process with the text "processes running".

```
my $process =`ps aux | grep '[c]pu2006' -c `;

my $process2= "$process" . " processes running\n";

print $process2;
```

I want the output to be:

```
3 processes running
```

But it turned out to be:

```
3   
processes running
```

Can someone help me with this code?

Comment: add `chomp $process;` before your print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your $process variable contains a number 3 and a line feed.

You can remove the linefeed with chop or chomp.

So your script becomes:

```
my `$process =ps aux | grep '[c]pu2006' -c`;
chomp($process);
my $process2= "$process" . " processes running\n";
print $process2;
```

chop and chomp are a bit confusing...

If you are using unix you can use chop because unix uses only '\n' as a line separator.

If you are using windows you can use chomp because chomp is smart enough to know what the input line separator is and will remove two characters \r and \n.

Best practice is to use chomp.

If you want to clean it up a bit you could also say:

```
chomp (my $process =`ps aux | grep '[c]pu2006' -c`);
print "$process processes running\n";
```

Comment: The `chop` part is confusing. Maybe explain the difference?

Comment: **chomp**
This is an alternative to the chop() function. It removes characters at the end of strings corresponding to the $INPUT_LINE_SEPARATOR ($/). It returns the number of characters removed. It can be given a list of strings upon which to perform this operation. When given no arguments, the operation is performed on $_.


**chop**
This function removes the last character of a string and returns that character. If given a list of arguments, the operation is performed on each one and the last character chopped is returned.


source: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=135462

Comment: @simbabque I tried to explain it. I probably should just have never mentioned chop!

Comment: @JohnC your explanation is very useful. Thanks!

Comment: @liyanaross great, I got you to read the documentation. Well done! :)